# Accessing Action Mailer templates in one application, from another application that uses the same database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have two separate Rails applications that both use the same database.
One application has ActionMailer templates set up to send various types emails.

The second application however also needs to be able to send emails using some of these templates.

I don't want to have to duplicate all the templates from one application into the other since that seems quite sub optimal and error prone. What is the best way to enable the second application to be able to send emails that are setup in the first application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking two questions here which is very bad practise for Stack Overflow.  You should make one post per question.  I'm just going to address the first question about sharing email templates.

One way is to put all of the templates which you want to be shared into a new folder in app A and then make a symbolic link in the corresponding place in app B.  Rails (and Git) are perfectly happy with this sort of thing.

eg, in your rails folder for appB

```
ln -s ../appA/app/views/shared_emails app/views/shared_emails
```

This assumes that appA and appB's folders are sitting next to each other.  If they aren't you can change the first part to have the correct navigation to appA's folder but you should keep it as a relative path, not an absolute path, since relative paths are more easy to keep in sync on both your server and your local machine (the absolute path is likely to be different on your server and local machine).